# How can `popstate` event be used to catch location change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-history

I'm looking through angularjs source code and particulary at `onUrlChange` method:

```
  self.onUrlChange = function(callback) {
    // TODO(vojta): refactor to use node's syntax for events
    if (!urlChangeInit) {
      // We listen on both (hashchange/popstate) when available, as some browsers (e.g. Opera)
      // don't fire popstate when user change the address bar and don't fire hashchange when url
      // changed by push/replaceState

      // html5 history api - popstate event
      if ($sniffer.history) jqLite(window).on('jqLite(window).on('popstate', cacheStateAndFireUrlChange);', cacheStateAndFireUrlChange);
      // hashchange event
      jqLite(window).on('hashchange', cacheStateAndFireUrlChange);

      urlChangeInit = true;
    }
```

The docs say:

> The callback is called when the url is changed from outside of
>   angular:
>
> - user types different url into address bar

I don't really understand how can a callback `cacheStateAndFireUrlChange` be triggered if a user types different url into address bar. If a user does so, the browser will navigate to different page where there will be no `cacheStateAndFireUrlChange` function. What am I missing here?

Comment: This is for the case when user stays at your application, but types different route. For example route changed from `https://example.com/myapp#users` to `https://example.com/myapp#records`

Comment: @Andrey, thanks, so you think it's not used in `html5mode(true)`?

Comment: Yes, I suppose. I've fiddled with it in html5mode and `cacheStateAndFireUrlChange` never got called. Pretty reasonable, because browser did a full page request.

Comment: @Andrey, yeah, thanks for your efforts. I'm trying to understand how `html5mode` works, and just stumbled upon this functionality which is not related. The core functionality seems to be inside `$rootElement.on('click', function(event) {` in $locationProvider and in `$browser.$$checkUrlChange();` inside `$digest`